# Java, ArrayList Filtering String

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, filtering

I am trying to filter an ArrayList which are two objects and each object is one String block, this is the ArrayList's value:

```
[DataItem {
    ItemId='324e9c2b-2db0-407b-9ec8-66b707b2047f',
    SortPosition='2',
    Rname"Domino's Pizza",
    LatLat'sf_photo',
    LomgLong'1',
    Neighborhood 'flipstreet',
    Category 'fast-food',
    Address'Taif Street, Dhahrat Laban, Riyadh 12564'
 }, //there is a comma in this line to separate between the two objects
 DataItem {
     ItemId='e8b0e814-f9e0-4eb8-ae2f-b118f6b4e55d', 
     SortPosition='6', 
     Rname'بيت الشواية', 
     LatLat'sf_photo',
     LomgLong'1', 
     Neighborhood 'takhassusi', 
     Category 'Arabian', 
     Address '2506 Bilal Ibn Rabah, Tuwaiq, Riyadh 14921'
 }
]
```

Please be informed that anything inside the {} is considered a string, so my question is, how can I Filter out the object(s) with the Neighborhood of flipstreet in them? In this case it will only be object one.

Comment: Are The Objects in JSON?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am new to java so if you have a thread that you can inform me of I will be delighted because i have no idea on how to approach this situation

Comment: If you are new, then you tackle a simple problem first, then you increase complexity and eventually you will be able to tackle this one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of the array is not a JSON string then you can opt for following approach.

Step 1: Access individual array element and store it in string. 
Step 2: Use String API to check if the string contains "Neighborhood 'flipstreet'", if Yes then output that element else continue with next string.

Following is the Java sample code.

public class ExampleCode {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dataItems = {"DataItem {"
            + "ItemId='324e9c2b-2db0-407b-9ec8-66b707b2047f',"
            + "SortPosition='2',"
            + "Rname \"Domino's Pizza\","
            + "LatLat'sf_photo',"
            + "LomgLong'1',"
            + "Neighborhood 'flipstreet',"
            + "Category 'fast-food',"
            + "Address'Taif Street, Dhahrat Laban, Riyadh 12564'}",
            "DataItem    {"
            + "ItemId='e8b0e814-f9e0-4eb8-ae2f-b118f6b4e55d',"
            + "SortPosition='6',"
            + "Rname'بيت الشواية',"
            + "LatLat'sf_photo',"
            + "LomgLong'1',"
            + "Neighborhood 'takhassusi',"
            + "Category 'Arabian',"
            + "Address '2506 Bilal Ibn Rabah, Tuwaiq, Riyadh 14921'"
            + "}"
    };

    String srchString="Neighborhood 'flipstreet'";

    for(String dataNode : dataItems) {
        if(dataNode.contains(srchString)){
            System.out.println(dataNode);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note: This is one of the solution and may not be the efficient solution!